# Extending Models in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, php

I'm receiving this error for some odd reason:

```
Fatal error: Class 'crud_model' not found in /application/models/shared_model.php on line 3
```

From this line:

```
class Shared_model extends crud_model {
```

Which has worked before in the past. Does anyone know what may be occuring here? The file is the respective folder, it's spelled correctly, and I've event tried the following with no positive results.

```
class Shared_model extends Crud_model {
```

and

```
class Shared_model extends Crud_Model {
```

Here is crud_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Crud_model extends CI_Model {

public $table_name;
public $pk;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Here is shared_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Shared_model extends Crud_model {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->pk = 'id';
    $this->table_name = 'shares';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure all your extended classes extend from the proper parent class, this might be the issue or you can load any dependent models to your parent.

Comment: I did, and still no go. Any thoughts beyond that?

Comment: does your crud_model extend CI_Model, because then you can extend crud_model with shared_model also in your constructor, are you calling `parent::__construct();`

Comment: Yes, my crud_model.php does extend CI_Model, and I am calling my `parent::__construct();` in each model. Still no go.

Comment: I've figured ou the issue on my own. Thank you very much for all of your help!

Comment: If you have figured this out please share your solution...

Comment: @Irussell810 What was your solution? I'm currently having a similar problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shared model should be saved in the codeigniter's core folder because the classes in the core folder are loaded early during execution

Answer (score 0):

A model's class must being with capital letters.